# Simple "then" promise between two anonymous functions

Tags: javascript

I have two anonymous functions that I want to execute consecutively. How can I do it with a promise ?

In this simplified example, the two functions that need to be executed consecutively are "renameReport" and "saveReport", inside the "saveAs" anonymous function.

"renameReport" and "saveReport" are both using jQuery to do AJAX calls. Simply Executing renameReport and saveReport on the next line won't do.

```
var renameReport = function () {
    ...
}

var saveReport= function () {
    ...
}

var saveAs = function () {
    renameReport().then(saveReport()); //not working
};
```

This result in an error : "TypeError: renameReport(...) is undefined"

Comment: You'll have to return a promise to be able to call `.then`. I'm not sure if your code is already async, but you don't need to use a promise if it isn't - you can just call each one consecutively

Comment: What does renameReport ,saveReport returns ?

Comment: That's unlikely to be the exact error. It should be more like `renameReport().then` is undefined...

Comment: And `saveReport()` is wrong.

Comment: Just do `renameReport(); saveReport();` and see if that works. Or [edit] your question to include more information.

Comment: You'd have to call saveReport in a callback too, rather than using the return value as the callback - `() => saveReport()`

Comment: renameReport and saveReport  doesn't return anything, but both function manipulate the same object. In save as, I want to assure that renameReport is called before saving my report under its new name.

Comment: @Pierre Then you can just call save report after. There is no need to make your code asynchronous.

Comment: Both save "renameReport" and "saveReport" are using some jquery and will eventually enter into conflict if I don't use promises...

Comment: @Pierre do they return a promise?

Comment: @VLAZ or use promises, for that matter?

Comment: @Kobe also a valid question. Using jQuery *by itself* doesn't mean there are asynchronous operations. If you're doing DOM manipulations, then those should be synchronous. Event handling is a different matter and AJAX another.

Comment: @VLAZ you are right, I should have precised that the jQuery parts are uses for AJAX calls.

Comment: @Pierre in that case, you should return the object that `$.ajax` itself returns. That is a jQuery Deferred object and a Promise-like. You can threat this as a Promise and/or [use the Deferred API](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) with it.

Comment: Well the question have been closed for being "off topic", I guess I'll have to redo it. I I have specified the desired behaviour in the first line and keep on topic though.

Comment: if you want the exact same api style, then i have created a plunker for you. Have a look at this. This is just an example. By this way you can have the end result as function1().then(function2).then(function3).then(function1) and so on.... Here is the link. https://next.plnkr.co/edit/9Nztw2Noe0VTkX7QPR5C?p=info&preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to use promises you have to have promises and return them so it can be chained. So if you do have a function that has a promise, you are probably not returning that promise.

You are also calling the function and not referencing it in the then. When you add the `()` it executes the function and assigns what it returns to the `then`. So drop the `()` so it is not executed.

Basic program flow you would need to look like this.

```js
var renameReport = function () {
  console.log('renameReport')
  return new Promise( function (resolve, reject) { 
    window.setTimeout(function () {
      console.log('renameReport timeout')
      resolve('hello')  
    }, 2000)
  })
}

var saveReport = function (data) {
  console.log('saveReport', data)
}

var saveAs = function () {
    renameReport().then(saveReport);
}

saveAs()
```

Comment: I have trouble understanding the syntax of promises, but it appears that multiple part of my project use promises without explicitly creating it. I will try your solution though.

Comment: Well it is hard to know what it is without seeing the actual code. Could be as simple as if something returns a promise, you need to return it in the function call to use it. Better sample code in your question would give better answers.